# Should I use immutability for objects with functions only?

Tags: javascript, immutability, immutable.js

I use [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) in my project and try to not to use plain JS structures.

But I'm not sure if it makes any sense to convert objects that contain functions only into immutable ones.

Let's say I have `MathUtility.js`:

```
export default {
  sum (a, b) {
    return a + b
  },
  min (a, b) {
    return a - b
  }
 //etc. More utils methods
}
```

Is it any sense to do something like this instead:

```
export default Immutable.fromJS({
  sum (a, b) {
    return a + b
  },
  min (a, b) {
    return a - b
  }
 //etc. More utils methods
})
```

From my POV it's not a data object (hard to split data from functions in JS from time to time) so there is no point to do that, but I'm not sure.

Thanks

Comment: if these are just going to be helper functions like you have in `MathUtility ` then I would say you do not need `Immutable `. Seems redundant

Comment: You could use [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) if you wanted to make it harder for people to change your utility object later, I suppose.

Comment: I'd export each function separately. This would allow for treeshaking as well as made the binding permanent.

Comment: @marzelin Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think I can't use dynamic function names if I'd export them separately? I didn't mention it in example, but it's also a point for me

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Afaik `Object.freeze` may slow down performance a bit, but what's more important - why it's better than usage of `Immutable.fromJS()`

Comment: you  can change name of imports ie `import {sum as sumAlias} from ...`

Comment: `Immutable.fromJS` will convert your object to an `Immutable.Map`, `Object.freeze` keeps it as a plain object, for one thing. I doubt the speed differential between the native `Object.freeze` and non-native `Immutable.fromJS` would be anything that would make a difference in this case.

Comment: Why not make `MathUtility` a class?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst because "class" usually mean to be called to create an instance. And there is no point to having instances for utils. But yeah, of course, it can be a class, but honestly I can't see any reason for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, i don't see any value in converting these into immutable objects. in fact, there's a fairly big drawback: you can no longer call these utility functions directly.

using your example:

```
var utils = Immutable.fromJS({
  sum (a, b) {
    return a + b;
  },
  min (a, b) {
    return a - b;
  }
});

utils.sum; // => undefined
utils.get('sum'); // => function
utils.get('sum')(1, 2) // => 3
```

that's pretty awkward imho.

Comment: Actually, you may do `.toJS()` after importing the `utils`, but in general, - I think you're right